# Firebase array-contains where clause does not find logical match

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firebase Firestore, I am trying to use `array-contains` to make a match a list of Ids.

Object Model:

```
requests[collection]
--qualifiers[array of strings]
--[0]:"6XH61BvwgW2oWBzxqEuA"
--[1]:"dmt6hn0u1gtEPX13QwDS"
```

If I query array-contains like so:

```
  await fire
  .firestore()
  .collection("requests")
  .where("qualifiers", "array-contains", ["6XH61BvwgW2oWBzxqEuA","dmt6hn0u1gtEPX13QwDS"])
  .get()
```

I get no results. However, if I switch this to an `array-contains-any`, amatch is made and results are returned.

I have double checked the values in the `qualifiers` array of strings field on the `requests` document and they only contain the two string ids mentioned above.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `array-contains` you have to pass any one string id.

```
await fire
  .firestore()
  .collection("requests")
  .where("qualifiers", "array-contains", "6XH61BvwgW2oWBzxqEuA")
  .get()

or

await fire
  .firestore()
  .collection("requests")
  .where("qualifiers", "array-contains", "dmt6hn0u1gtEPX13QwDS")
  .get()
```

- `array-contains` - takes a value for the comparison operation
- `array-contains-any` query returns documents where the given field is an `array` that contains one or more of the comparison values.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership